# Sharing callbacks globally in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook that returns a callback function:

```
const {scrollToComponent} = useVisibilityHandler(ref);
```

Now I want to store this callback in such a way that it should be accessible to some other Component too:

```
// Header.tsx
const Header = () => {
    // I need to access the callback created in the above function here.
}
```

Since State management tools strongly discourage storing callbacks due to their non serializable nature I want to know what is the best practice followed to share callbacks globally among different functional components.

Comment: A [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is usually the weapon of choice when you want to broadcast a value to many unrelated customers

Comment: I am using redux right now. However a callback is a non serializable value which is discouraged to be stored in global context/redux store.